PHPMailer Not Sending Emails on Hosting Server, Works on Localhost with Gmail SMTP
I’m having trouble getting PHPMailer to send emails through Gmail’s SMTP server after uploading my project to a hosting server. It works perfectly on my localhost, but once I upload it, it fails to send emails, and I’m not sure why.
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';         // Gmail SMTP server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'your_email@gmail.com';      // Replace with your Gmail address
$mail->Password = 'your_app_password';         // Gmail App Password
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
$mail->Port = 465;

Additional Context
I’m using Gmail’s app password because my account has two-factor authentication enabled.
PHPMailer is updated to the latest version.
Only Error I've encountered was the smtp cannot connect to the server.
I tried doing this things:
Verified that the code works perfectly on my localhost environment.
Double-checked the Gmail app password and SMTP settings to make sure they’re correct.
Checked with my hosting provider, who confirmed they aren’t blocking any SMTP or restricting traffic.
Tried both ssl on port 465 and tls on port 587, but neither works on the hosting server.
I hope someone can help me with this, Thankyou!

If I remember correctly, if you are using port 465 in gmail smtp then set $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#enabling-debug-output

No error messages?

Issue with sending emails through Gmail’s SMTP server.
Check Server Firewall and Outbound Connections.
Check PHPMailer's Debugging Output.
Update PHP Version and Extensions.
Testing with Another SMTP Server.
By enabling PHPMailer's debug output, checking server restrictions, and ensuring your PHP configuration is correct, you should be able to get more details on what's going wrong.

Please don't just dump all available options in short form
